# What does it mean by a matrix being bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does it means each entry is bounded?

Also, finally, given the domain is orthogonal group, I am aware that the range of $F$ is identity, which is closed. But how can I show the domain is?

By the way, it comes to my mind that - does this function has inverse: $F(A) = AA^T$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) I assume that you have a sequence of matrices in mind. If so, you can use the same concept of boundedness that you have say $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ by supplying the extra data of a norm on the space of matrices. Coincidentally, all choices of norms are [equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Definition) in this case so indeed you could take as the definition that each entry is bounded.

2) Hint: The preimage of a closed set under a continuous map is closed.

3) No, since it is not injective (take two different orthogonal matrices and notice that they are mapped to the same point).

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much! Though have two minor issues: I "know"(not really since I don't know how to prove it) that result: the preimage of an open set under a continuous function is open, but that the image of an open set need not be. The counter example is easy to find, but by any chance do you happen to know where I can trace a proof of the first part? Secondly, I know that the choices of norms are equivalent - thanks a lot for your reference as well, but why hence we can reduce matrices are bounded to indicies are? Thank you~

Comment: For the first part: What is your definition of continuity? Often people take the property of preimages of opens being open as the definition, but then your question is not very interesting. Perhaps you've defined it using $\varepsilon$s and $\delta$s? In that case, the fact is a standard exercise in using the definitions which you can probably solve, either by hand or by Google. For the second question, by the fact about equivalences, the question is reduced to proving it for the [Frobenius norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_norm#Frobenius_norm) on ...

Comment: ... matrices. For this norm, it is easy to see both that if the Frobenius norm is bounded, so are all entries (for if some entry were unbounded, so would the Frobenius norm be), and contrarily that if all entries are bounded, so is the Frobenius norm by the same argument.

Comment: That's so helpful, I got it, thanks so much. =)

Comment: Oh, got it, thanks so much @fuglede!!